# How to remove string with comma in a big string?

Tags: php, yii

I'm a newbie in PHP ,andnow I'm struck on this problem . I have a string like this :

```
$string = "qwe,asd,zxc,rty,fgh,vbn";
```

Now I want when user click to "qwe" it will remove "qwe," in $string

```
Ex:$string = "asd,zxc,rty,fgh,vbn";
```

Or remove "fhg,"

```
Ex:$string = "asd,zxc,rty,vbn";
```

I try to user str_replace but it just remove the string and still have a comma before the string like this:

```
$string = ",asd,zxc,rty,fgh,vbn";
```

Anyone can help? Thanks for reading

Comment: Why you don´t work with an array?

Comment: as panther has said this would be easier to manipulate thru arrays, explode array search unset implode

Comment: can you give me an example ? I don't know much how to work with arrays . Thanks

Comment: That comment above just earned you a downvote. This is not a place to learn programming. At least make an attempt to learn PHP. Working with arrays is a language basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$break=explode(",",$string);
$new_array=array();
foreach($break as $newData)
{
 if($newData!='qwe')
 {
  $new_array[]=$newData;
 }
}
$newWord=implode(",",$new_array);

echo $newWord;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your objective, array is your best friend.

```
$string = "qwe,asd,zxc,rty,fgh,vbn";
$ExplodedString = explode( "," , $string ); //Explode them separated by comma

$itemToRemove = "asd";

foreach($ExplodedString as $key => $value){ //loop along the array
    if( $itemToRemove == $value ){ //check if item to be removed exists in the array
        unset($ExplodedString[$key]); //unset or remove is found
    }
}

$NewLook = array_values($ExplodedString); //Re-index the array key

print_r($NewLook); //print the array content

$NewLookCombined = implode( "," , $NewLook);

print_r($NewLookCombined); //print the array content after combined back
```

Answer (score 1):

here the solution

```
$string = "qwe,asd,zxc,rty,fgh,vbn";
      $clickword = "vbn";          
      $exp = explode(",", $string);
      $imp =  implode(" ", $exp);

      if(stripos($imp, $clickword) !== false) {

       $var =  str_replace($clickword," ", $imp);

      }

      $str =  preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ', $var);

      $newexp = explode(" ", trim($str));

      $newimp = implode(",", $newexp);
      echo $newimp;
```

Comment: It still cannot remove the last string . Example : It not remove "vbn"

Answer (score 0):

You could try preg_replace https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php if you have the module set up. It will allow you to optionally replace trailing or leading commas easily:

```
preg_replace("/,*$providedString,*/i", '', "qwe,asd,zxc,rty,fgh,vbn");
```